# Rails 4 combining output from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner, so this question maybe very elementary. I appreciate any help. I have three models - one Metal that does a query of a database to get a price and another QuoteMetal which is nested through has_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for in Lead. I need the results of the query conducted through the Metal model to be available in the lead collection so I can display the results in the view.

My question: how do I get those query results (specifically the price attribute) to be in the Lead instance variable. Of if not the lead instance variable - what is the best way to display the results. Below is my code.

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lead = Lead.new
    @quote_metal = @lead.quote_metals.build
    @quote_melee = @lead.quote_melees.build
    @quote_diamond = @lead.quote_diamonds.build
  end

  def create
    #raise params.inspect
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    @qm = @lead.quote_metals.map { |f| Metal.calculate_metal(f).first}

    #@lead.quote_metals.each do |f|
    #    f[:price] = @qm[:price].to_i
    #end
    @lead = Lead.create!(lead_params)
  end

  def show
  end

private

    def lead_params
        params.require(:lead).permit([:name, :email, :phone, :zip, :note, :method, 
            quote_metals_attributes: [:id, :metal, :weight, :unit, :price],
      quote_melees_attributes: [:shape, :quality, :quantity, :totalweight, :size],
      quote_diamonds_attributes: [:shape, :size, :color, :clarity]
      ])
    end

end
```

Metal Model:

```
class Metal < ActiveRecord::Base

    enum metal: {platinum: 1, palladium: 2, "10_karat_gold": 3, "14_karat_gold": 4,
                  "18_karat_gold": 5, "22_karat_gold": 6, silver: 7}
    enum unit: {pennyweight: 1, grams: 2, ounce: 3, pound: 4}

    attr_accessor :weight

    #Validations
    validates :metal, :unit, :weight, presence: true


    scope :calculate_metal, ->(quote_metal) {
        where(metal: QuoteMetal.metals[quote_metal.metal],
      unit: QuoteMetal.units[quote_metal.unit])
    }

    scope :multiple, ->(quote_metal){

    }
end
```

Create.html.erb

```
<pre>
  <%= @qm.inspect %>
  <br>
<%= @lead.quote_metals.inspect %>
  <br>
<%= @qm.inspect %>
  <br>
<%= @qm2.inspect %>
</pre>
```

Output:

```
  [#<Metal id: 11, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff01dac4be8,'0.1367E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2015-05-26 10:36:38", updated_at: nil, weight: nil>, #<Metal id: 11, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff01da96450,'0.1367E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2015-05-26 10:36:38", updated_at: nil, weight: nil>]


#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<QuoteMetal id: 231, lead_id: 176, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: nil, weight: #<BigDecimal:7ff01cc71320,'0.1E1',9(18)>, quote: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 18:26:46", updated_at: "2015-07-14 18:26:46">, #<QuoteMetal id: 232, lead_id: 176, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: nil, weight: #<BigDecimal:7ff01ca49d90,'0.2E1',9(18)>, quote: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 18:26:46", updated_at: "2015-07-14 18:26:46">]>


[#<Metal id: 11, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff01dac4be8,'0.1367E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2015-05-26 10:36:38", updated_at: nil, weight: nil>, #<Metal id: 11, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff01da96450,'0.1367E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2015-05-26 10:36:38", updated_at: nil, weight: nil>]


[[#<Lead id: nil, name:..., note: "asdf", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Metal id: 11, metal: 2, unit: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff01dac4be8,'0.1367E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2015-05-26 10:36:38", updated_at: nil, weight: nil>]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the `calculate_metal` scope?  Also, where do you calculate price?  Does your `Lead` model have a price attribute you wish to populate?

Comment: The calculate_metal is an SQL query. The results of that query have the price attribute. I want to copy that price over to the Lead model, which through the quote_metal model has a price attribute. Also, since it is a has_many relationship, the Lead model has more than one quote_metals with multiple prices.

Comment: Yes I can see that `calculate_metal` is a scoped query but I don't see what it accomplishes.  Nevertheless, if you have a lead `@lead` with many quote_metals, each having a price, you can iterate through `@lead.quote_metals` in your view and each element will have a price.  Are you looking for the view code to do this given a `@lead`?  Or are you trying to get `@lead` populated correctly?

Comment: A form populates Lead (instance variable) and has a field for a price (which is nill). The calculate_metal query goes a finds that price but puts it in a different object. I am trying to add that price found in the query to the Lead object. Any ideas? I appreciate your help.

Comment: So you have an attribute `Lead.price`?  In your controller, you can update your `Lead` instance with the price (e.g. `@lead.price = calculated_price`).  But if there are multiple prices, it is not clear which one should be populated in the `Lead` instance.  Maybe we can chat quickly on this.

Comment: How do we chat? I would love to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83255/discussion-between-joe-d-and-steve-klein).